# Implementing Applovin Ads with Swift & SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, applovin

I would like some help with integrating interstitial ads from Applovin using Swift. Currently, I have managed to successfully integrate the SDK and initialize it using `ALSdk.initializeSdk()`. I have a folder in my project directory called `Applovin` which contains: `headers` folder (with all the .h files inside) and `libApplovinSdk.a`.

I have a `BridgingHeader.h` file in which I am importing the relevant frameworks

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Chartboost/Chartboost.h>
#import <Chartboost/CBNewsfeed.h>
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>
#import <AdSupport/AdSupport.h>

#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import<CoreTelephony/CTCallCenter.h>
#import<CoreTelephony/CTCall.h>
#import<CoreTelephony/CTCarrier.h>
#import<CoreTelephony/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h>
#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>
#import <CoreMedia/CoreMedia.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>

// Core SDK
#import "ALErrorCodes.h"
#import "ALSdk.h"
#import "ALSdkSettings.h"
#import "ALTargetingData.h"
#import "ALPostbackService.h"
#import "ALPostbackDelegate.h"

// Standard Ads
#import "ALAd.h"
#import "ALAdDisplayDelegate.h"
#import "ALAdLoadDelegate.h"
#import "ALAdRewardDelegate.h"
#import "ALAdService.h"
#import "ALAdSize.h"
#import "ALAdType.h"
#import "ALAdUpdateDelegate.h"
#import "ALAdVideoPlaybackDelegate.h"
#import "ALAdView.h"
#import "ALIncentivizedInterstitialAd.h"
#import "ALInterstitialAd.h"

// Native Ads
#import "ALNativeAd.h"
#import "ALNativeAdService.h"
#import "ALNativeAdPrecacheDelegate.h"
#import "ALNativeAdLoadDelegate.h"
```

In my `AppDelegate` i have the following methods, what do I need to put inside these methods?

```
func adService(adService: ALAdService, didLoadAd ad: ALAd) {

}

func adService(adService: ALAdService, didFailToLoadAdWithError code: Int32) {

}
```

I am attempting to show ads using the following code but `ALInterstitialAd.isReadyForDisplay()` is always false, I am probably missing something very obvious but I am not sure what it is, any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
if ALInterstitialAd.isReadyForDisplay() == true {
        ALInterstitialAd.show()
    } else {
        println("No Applovin Ad available to show")
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely need to enable "Test Mode" for your app in the AppLovin dashboard in order to force test ads to serve for your area.  Please send any questions to support@applovin.com for further assistance.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what it was. Thank you

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but turning on Test mode doesn't seem like the answer because that's not going to be on for the release of the app.  If I ignore the isReadyForDisplay flag it will force the ad to load and show.  Why won't it load the ad in the background if it's not in test mode?